# segfault when allocate memory dynamically in C

Tags: c

I've been trying to build a priority queue in C. 
First of all, I do some initialization work such as allocating space. 
The following is the *Initialize* routine and *PriorityQueue* is a pointer.

```
void Initialize(int MaxElement, PriorityQueue H)
{
   if (MaxElement < MinPQSize)
     printf("Priority queue size is too small");

   if (!(H = (PriorityQueue)malloc(sizeof(struct HeapStruct))))
     printf("Out of space!!!");

   if (!(H->Elements = (ElementType *)malloc((MaxElement+1) * sizeof(ElementType))))
     printf("Out of space!!!");

   H->Capacity = MaxElement;
   H->Size = 0;

   H->Elements[0] = MinData;
}
```

Here is how the test code is like

```
 int MaxElement = 15;
 PriorityQueue myHeap;
 Initialize(MaxElement, myHeap);
```

But when I try to insert elements into the heap, a segmentation fault pops out. 
It can be solved by simply returning the *PriorityQueue* pointer from *Initialize* routine.

```
 PriorityQueue Initialize(int MaxElement, PriorityQueue H)
 {
   ...
   return H;
 }
 myHeap = Initialize(MaxElement, myHeap);
```

So what's happening under the hood? 
Is free() invoked when the function returns without a return value? 
Thx in advance!

Comment: I think you need some `accept_rate++`.

Answer (score 6):

No, even though the `H` that you're passing in is a pointer, you're trying to change it within the function (with your first `malloc`). In order to change something, you need to pass a pointer to it. In this case, that means a pointer *to a pointer:*

```
void Initialize (int MaxElem, PriorityQueue *H) {
    if (MaxElem < MinPQSize)
        printf("Priority queue size is too small");

    if (!(*H = (PriorityQueue)malloc(sizeof(struct HeapStruct))))
        printf("Out of space!!!");

    if (!((*H)->Elements = (ElemType *)malloc((MaxElem+1) * sizeof(ElemType))))
        printf("Out of space!!!");

    (*H)->Capacity = MaxElem;
    (*H)->Size = 0;
    (*H)->Elements[0] = MinData;
}
```

Without the extra level on indirection, the `H` that you change within the function is isolated to the function - it is *not* reflected back to the caller.

A couple of other points you may want to consider:

- You shouldn't cast the return from `malloc`, it can hide certain errors that you really *do* want to know about.
- If your second malloc fails, you should free the result of the first `malloc`.
- If either of your `malloc` calls fail, you should return rather than continue, since continuing will cause undefined behaviour if you dereference the null pointer.
- You probably don't want to print things from general purpose functions since that's probably an unwanted behaviour. If you must indicate a problem, you're better off passing back an indication to the caller to let them handle it in their own way.

Although to be honest, I actually like the versions that return a value (with no need to pass it in beforehand since you're clearly creating a *new* thing). Something like this should do:

```
PriorityQueue Initialize (int MaxElem) {
    PriorityQueue H;

    if (MaxElem < MinPQSize) {
        printf("Priority queue size is too small");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!(H = malloc(sizeof(*H)))) {
        printf("Out of space!!!");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!(H->Elements = malloc((MaxElem+1) * sizeof(ElementType)))) {
        printf("Out of space!!!");
        free (H);
        return NULL;
    }

    H->Capacity = MaxElem;
    H->Size = 0;
    H->Elements[0] = MinData;

    return H;
}

PriorityQueue myHeap = Initialize (MaxElement);
```

Comment: +1 for such a complete answer. Also for advising against casting malloc's return.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Actually, your second version is the original solution from the book but I don't like the idea of returning a local variable. Well, it reminds me there is no such concrete thing as "pointer" and everything is passed by "value".

Comment: @manuzhang, you think rethink your "returning a local variable" thoughts. You're actually returning a _copy_ of the pointer to malloced memory (which persists across function returns).

Comment: yeah, I know that works but what if the memory is not on the heap on other occasions. I believe it's a matter of habit.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the pointer by value, allow me to illustrate:

```
char* c = 0;

void set_c(char* ptr)
{
    ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);       
}

// a copy of c is sent in, 
set_c(c);
// c doesn't point to the newly allocated data!
```

To set it correctly, you have to pass your pointer BY pointer, like this:

```
void set_c_correctly(char** ptr)
{
   *ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
}

// a pointer to c is passed in
set_c_correctly(&c);

// now c points to the newly allocated data
```

Comment: The OP isn't actually passing a pointer anywhere in the code.

Comment: From line 3 of the original question:  "PriorityQueue is a pointer."  I know it's bad to make assumptions, but it's likely that `PriorityQueue` is `typedef`'d as a `HeapStruct*`.

Comment: Yes, I missed that, sorry.  That changes my answer completely.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++.  C does not have the `new` operator.

Comment: `typedef struct HeapStruct *PriorityQueue;`